How to check the size of a HTML heading
Testing for a heading on a page (Users) which is h4 size and getting rather stuck.
Currently trying the following, but to no avail:
await expect(pageFixture.page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Users' })).toHaveAttribute('header','h4');


It's not an attribute; that would match e.g. <h1 header="h4">Users</h1>. If you want to select by the heading role, they have a level as they have a name - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78416399/3001761.
